# How can I fix the spacing/add spacing between fancyhdr and document? (with MWE)

Tags: spacing, formatting, header-footer, fancyhdr, geometry

I am trying to fix the spacing between my header (using fancyhdr) and the body text of my paper. I am using MacTeX / XeLaTeX.

When a section title begins a page, it looks like this:
[image: page 1]

On normal pages, it looks like this:
[image: page 2]

My ultimate goal is for there to be ~1in between the edge of the paper and the beginning of the body text, and ~10pt between the header line and the start of the body text (for both the section title and normal text).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\raggedright
\setlength\RaggedRightParindent{.5in}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{Name}
\lhead{Title}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\section{Blah}
\lipsum

\pagebreak
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: You can use  the optional argument `headsep=10pt` when loading  `geometry`.

Comment: And adjust the `headheight` at the same time. `\usepackage[margin=1in, headheight=15pt, headsep=10pt]{geometry}`

Comment: Thank you guys @PietervanOostrum @Bernard!! Will one of you make it an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set `headsep` (and `headheigth` to be complete) with the `geometry` statement.

```
\usepackage[margin=1in, headheight=15pt, headsep=10pt]{geometry}
```